# Prevent redirects from showing up in browser history

Tags: php, html, url

I have a subdomain, and when I a user presses a button from some other website, they will be directed to my main domain through the subdomain, here's the code inside the subomain file `index.php`:

```
<?php header("Location: example.com"); ?>
```

problem is, I don't want the user to know about my subdomain URL, because it will be stored in their browsing history. Is there a way to hide it completely when they get directed to my main domain?

Comment: You need a neuralyzer. Why this is a problem for you?

Comment: @shingo I'm making cheat proof website point system, where if the user came to my website through some other website that referenced me, then they will gain a point. And I cannot use HTTP_REFERER since it shows a blank, so I'm using a subdomain to check where he came from

Comment: @shingo so can I prevent storing my website url in visitors history?

Comment: You can't, the browser is in my computer, so I have the right to know addresses I have visited. Image there is a malware website that can attack your security but it uses some magical mechanism to hide the history, will you be satisfied?

Comment: If HTTP_REFERER is blank, you can redirect them to a page and tell them to visit your website from the index page or you can ask them for authentication first.

Comment: If you need this level of verification that the request is actually from another site, you should work out a more secure system of referrals from the other site based on signed tokens.